# Get value from array by key or falsey value if key doesn't exist / isn't truthy

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array:

```
$a = array('a' => 1,'b' => 2,'c' => null);
```

I want to find a way of accessing the value of an element for a given key, and if the key doesn't exist, a falsey value.

With the example above, I'd like `$a['d']` to give me a falsey value. (similar to JavaScript: `({}).b // -> undefined`).

How can I do that?

Edit: In my specific case, I do not care if e.g. `$a['c'] => false`.

Comment: php7 `$d = $a['d'] ?? false` php 5.6 `$d = $a['d'] ?: false`

Comment: Thank you very much sir!

Comment: Second question, can you do `$a['d'] === $a['f']` somehow where neither of those keys may exist? Or would id be `($a['d'] ?? null) === ($a['f'] ?? false)`

Comment: Make sure you read about them [here](http://php.net/ternary#language.operators.comparison.ternary) and [here](http://php.net/ternary#language.operators.comparison.coalesce) as they may behave unexpectedly if value d did exist in the array and is null / is a falsey value.

Comment: You can chain ?? so you can do something like this `$d = $a['d'] ?? $a['f'] ?? false;`, you can also chain ?: but it gets a little complicated to follow.

Answer (score 3):

In PHP 7.0 and upwards you can use the *null coalescing operator*:

```
$d = $a['d'] ?? false;
```

In PHP 5.3 and upwards you can use a *ternary statement*:

```
$d = isset($a['d']) ? $a['d'] : false;
```

Tested below in PHP7.0.20

PHP Script

```
$a = array('a' => 1,'b' => 2,'c' => 3);

$b1 = $a['b'] ?? false;
$b2 = isset($a['b']) ? $a['b'] : false;
$b3 = $a['b'] ?: false;

$d1 = $a['d'] ?? false;
$d2 = isset($a['d']) ? $a['d'] : false;
// Undefined Error
// $d3 = $a['d'] ?: false;

var_dump([
    'b1' => $b1,
    'b2' => $b2,
    'b3' => $b3,
    'd1' => $d1,
    'd2' => $d2,
    // 'd3' => $d3
]);
```

Console output

```
| => php test.php
    array(5) {
        ["b1"]=>int(2)
        ["b2"]=>int(2)
        ["b3"]=>int(2)
        ["d1"]=>bool(false)
        ["d2"]=>bool(false)
    }
```

For reference, see:

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary
- http://php.net/manual/de/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op)

Comment: _Notice: Undefined index: d_

Comment: the null coalesce for php7 returns the value 1 if the value is set instead of the actual value, and the 'shorthand' version would return 1 instead of the value as well.

Comment: Good point, I updated again and show the output of another, defined value.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should try:

```
echo empty($a['d'])?false:$a['d'];
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a function for this...

### THE ONLY CORRECT WAY

```
$my_array = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => null);

if(array_key_exists('d', $my_array)){
    // Do something
}
else{
    // Do something else
}
```

---

Also, pay extra attention to `'d' => null` because databases will gladly return `null` values

```
// The almost right way
$my_array = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => null);

$result = array_key_exists( 'd', $my_array ) ? $my_array['d'] : false;

var_dump( $result );

// The wrong way
$result = isset($my_array['d']) ? $my_array['d'] : false;

var_dump( $result );
```

I posted "The almost right way" because the value can literally be a `false`, see below:

```
$my_array = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => false);

// $result it going to be false but there is no way to tell if this is due to the key being missing or if the key's value is literally false
$result = array_key_exists( 'd', $my_array ) ? $my_array['d'] : false;
```

If the above occurs then all logic goes out the window.

Comment: You are right. I have updated the question, as in my specific case I this was not what I was after. However this is great.

Comment: @Dan I see. In that case, "The almost right way" would suffice for you.